# Windows: Cancel WOW6432Node mapping of registry keys when running reg command from 32-bit Java

Tags: java, windows, registry, cmd, wsh

I tried making registry changes by running WScript that runs `reg`, but it still gets re-routed to `WOW6432Node`.

Is there a way I can get either a WScript or CMD script (or Java) to force use of the 64bit section?

There are [functions for this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384129%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), but I do not know how to use them in WScript (VBScript/JScript) or Java.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to explicitly launch the 64-bit version of `reg.exe` from `%SystemRoot%\sysnative`.

Check first whether the folder exists.  If it doesn't, you're either on a 32-bit system or already running in 64-bit context, and you can just run the version from `%SystemRoot%\system32` as usual.